# Should a woman who gives birth and gets divorced shortly afterwards complete her period of waiting (iddat)?

Tags: sharia, talaq, husband-wife, iddah, baby

If a woman gives birth to a child but she has not had contact with her husband for 4 months during pregnancy, and 1 month after giving  birth she gets divorced without a contract with him, should she complete her [iddat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah) (period of waiting)?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly answered by:

> Divorced women remain in waiting for three periods ...
>   <sub>[Qur'an 2:228](https://quran.com/2/228)</sub>

Here, periods are considered menstrual cycles (see e.g. [Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=228&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)).  However, after giving birth it's likely menses is not taking place, where the Qur'an says it's three months:

> And those who no longer expect menstruation among your women - if you doubt, then their period is three months ...
>   <sub>[Qur'an 65:4](https://quran.com/65/4)</sub>